# Multiple parameters taking up multiple lines in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am trying to develop a C# windows form application using visual studio. It connects to a microsoft access database. I have a form that saves data to the database. I have text boxes that I need to link to the database field. My problem is I have a lot of textbox names and values for the textbox to code so I need to do it on multiple lines. I did a search on this site and I see you can use the @ symbol in front of the first set of double quotes which encases the first group of parameters but I am not sure how to deal withe the second group of parameters which is the list of values. It would be something like:

```
command.CommandText = @"insert into xxx (xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx)
```

but when it gets to

```
values('" + txt_ID.Text + "','" + txt_Nickname.Text + "')"
```

I get an error saying

> "newline in constant"

and that it expects either a `";"` or a `"}"`.

So basically I have to set of parameters that I am trying to code on multiple lines.

Comment: don't do that. use parameteirized queries, not string concat.

Comment: single quotes `'` are for characters, double quotes `"` are for strings.

Comment: If you're using Access 2010 +, it supports the use of Stored Procedures. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287545/how-do-i-make-a-stored-procedure-in-ms-access  Use those instead

Comment: This  [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25029197/c-sharp-microsoft-access-parameterized-queries-not-doing-its-job) contains collection of links to other questions how to use parametrized queries with Access...

Comment: Can you paste exactly the code which is failing? Your two examples don't match up - if you paste exactly what the CommandText string looks like it will be much easier to give you feedback.

Comment: if you want a double quote inside a string use the backslash to escape the quote: `Console.WriteLine("She said, \"Hello\"");` will produce `She said, "Hello"`

Comment: command.CommandText = @"insert into Wendys (ID,Nickname,ProjectNumber,ProjectYear,StoreNumber,StreetAddress,City,State,Zipcode,
AssetType,BaseModel,BldgPrototypeYear,UpgradeClass,ExtgBldgWallStructure,StructuralDwgs,BladeDesign,CurtainWall,
PUWVestibule,NonPUWVestibule,DriveThruType,TrashEnclosure,DigitalStatic,Patio,SelfServe,SpandrelGlass,CounterStyle,RaisedCeiling,
KitchenWork,ElecGasHeat,ElecGasFryers,ElecGasGrilles,BlockBands,Notes) values('" + txt_ID.Text + "','" + txt_Nickname.Text + "',
' " + txt_Nickname.Text + "')";

Comment: i had to shorten it up to paste the code but i think you should still be able to see. i was trying to do it with multiple line but i wasn't sure how to write the syntax for the values

Comment: Again, parameters are what you want.  Someone is probably entering a NewLine into one of your text fields.  Have a read here: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-A1-Injection  Injection is still a HUGE problem, so be part of the solution.  Additional reading here: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection

Comment: Thanks but its most likely just an error in syntax on my part. I'm fairly new at c# programming so i'm probably not doing something right. I will look at some of the earlier responses & see if something works. Basically im trying to match up the text box name with the name in the fiels of the database. When it gets to the value part of the code is when i get the error. I put the @ symbol in front of the first line of my code but i was having trouble with the value parameters with the multiple lines

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use parameterized queries:

```
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO mytable (id, nickname) VALUES (@id, @nickname)";

OleDbParameter[] parameters = new OleDbParameter[2];
parameters[0] = new OleDbParameter("@id", Convert.ToInt32(txt_ID.Text));
parameters[1] = new OleDbParameter("@nickname", txt_Nickname.Text);

command.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
```

Keep in mind that the parameters **must** be added in the same order they appear in the query. `OleDb` doesn't use the names but only the order.

That is why you could use "?" as placeholders in the query with the exact same result

```
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO mytable (id, nickname) VALUES (?, ?)";
```

Comment: Only `SqlParameter` won't work too well on an Access Db.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Never used Access Db to be honest, this is to give the OP an idea of what he should do. Imagine it as pseudo code.

Comment: Updated the answer.